# Synonyms / slang words in American English to express "I am very excited for something"?

Tags: phrase-requests, american-english, british-english, idiom-requests

In British English we can say "I am keen to do something with you". Also: "Would you like to go to a concert?" A: "I'm keen for that!".

What are some equivalents in American English? Is it "I want to do that" or "I am excited for that"? Those seem very generic.

I'm looking for a phrase that is used in everyday conversation.

Comment: "Good slang" will be highly subjective. What audience are you addressing?

Comment: As a Brit, I can't say that *"I'm keen for xxx!"* sounds particularly natural - I'm more used to hearing people say "*I'm keen **on** xxx!*". But *keen* is more likely to be used where *xxx* is an area of interest, rather than a one-off activity like going to a concert. In that context *"I'm [really* or *well] up for that!"* is certainly more common in SE UK.

Comment: To my judgment, neither "keen for that" nor "excited for that" is a recognisable phrase.

Comment: @ColinFine I think it’s the wrong preposition that throws it. It should be *keen/excited **about*** something, no?

Comment: I want to stay out of the preposition argument, but I'd like to add that my American ear wouldn't be put off by _keen_.  It wouldn't strike me as particularly odd, and I've personally heard it/said it.

Comment: 1 - 'keen' is not in current American English usage; it sounds very much 1920's slang, like 'swell' for 'good'.

2 - In AmE one is 'excited' -about- something (meaning experiencing the thing makes one excited. 'excited for' would mean that your excited feeling is sympathetic for someone who has experienced something good).

Comment: @Mitch: Overuse of _keen_ would indeed sound outdated, but the word itself is nonetheless bantered about plenty nowadays, perhaps as a mild way of saying "enthusiastic about," e.g.: _"Matador is a label that we've always been keen on. Everyone there is a music person rather than a business person: Everyone's going out to shows and just keen on music in general..."_ (Lee Ranaldo, in an interview with _Billboard_, 2009). Then again, he's a musician, so maybe he's just picked that word up from British musicians 8^)

Comment: @RegDwight: I think the OP mixed his metaphors. S/B, I am excited FOR someone, or ABOUT something. I was wondering if you could reopen this question so I can post the above as an answer. Clearing up the confusion could be "constructive."

Answer (score 5):

For excitement or enthusiasm, one could try

1. I'm all over that
2. I'm psyched [up]
3. I'm pumped [up]
4. I'm stoked
5. I'm amped [up]
6. I'm jazzed [up]
7. I'm juiced
8. I'm fired [up]

Comment: (You might want to switch that to a numbered list so we can comment on them by number.)  Those are good. Of your list of 8, I would use #2 or maybe #4; I wouldn’t use #3 myself, but I have heard it.  #8 seems a bit old-fashioned. I think #5–7 might be from a music subculture, and that #1 sounds like teen-talk to my ancient ear.

Comment: "Psyched" was the one that popped into my mind.  The others are okay, too, but I'm really keen on #2.

Comment: I used to hear "I'm down with that!", especially from African American youth. I think most Americans would understand the expression with "keen", but would be less likely to use it.

Answer (score 4):

I’m not sure what’s so wrong with “keen”, but you might try “I’m up for that.” Pretty simple, but it should do.

Otherwise, it’s eager **to** do something, not eager **for** doing something.

Answer (score 2):

How about "I'm game!"?
It is heard quite often.